# Show password validation errors of a Zend Form on other action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

in all the examples I find of Zend_Form the view showing the form corresponds to the action in which it is processed. However, I want a view that displays multiple independent forms and separate actions to process each of the forms (whose view is not used).

Redirect to individual actions is not a problem, the forms are processed there but when validation errors appears, I want them displayed on the common view next to each item, Zend_Form style. As I understand, when a form is populated (with invalid data) errors are displayed automatically. Then, when a form is invalid, I use FlashMessenger to store the invalid content, then redirected to the main common action and populate the form with him.

The problem arises with the password fields. These, of course, refuse to be populated, and therefore do not show any error message. Could I display it without having to manually figure out which error occurred?

Thank you for your attention and your patience with my english :P

PS: For better understanding i append a sample code explaining what I do...

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    ...

    public function commonAction() {
        /*Initialize form objects*/
        $form1 = new Application_Form_Form1();
        ...
        $formN = new Application_Form_FormN();

        /*Fill forms if needed*/
        $flashMess = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
        if ($flashMess->hasMessages()) {
            $messages = $flashMess->getMessages();
            switch ($messages[1]) {
                case 'form1':
                    $form1->populate($messages[0]);
                    break;
                ...
                case 'formN':
                    $fotmN->populate($messages[0]);
                    break;
                default:
                    ...
                    break;
            }
        }

        /*Assign to the view*/
        $this->view->form1 = $form1;
        ...
        $this->view->formN = $formN;
    }

    public function form1Action() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $form1 = new Application_Form_Form1();
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form1->isValid($data)) {
                ...
            } else {
                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger($data);
                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('form1');
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('/test/common');
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand, when a form is populated (with invalid data) errors
>   are displayed automatically.

This is not the case, if you populate the form with invalid values, you will have to call `isValid` again in order to run the validators and mark the form and elements with the appropriate error messages.

You could also save the error messages for each element in the `FlashMessenger` and then re-attach the error messages back to each element, but you can also call `isValid` again.  If you ever used a form with a `File` element, you would have to save the error message as you would not be able to re-populate the element with the uploaded file.

> The problem arises with the password fields. These, of course, refuse
>   to be populated.

If you set the `renderPassword` flag (ex: `$el->setRenderPassword()`) on each password field, they will populate along with the rest of the values and when you call `isValid`, the password field will be validated and any appropriate error message would show up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is solved simply replacing the call to 'populate' with one to 'isValid' with, of course, the same argument. Now error messages appears as expected. I don't really want to fill the fields with the password because I think (feel, in fact) it isn't secure, I only want to show validation error messages.

Thank you!